# Jquery dynamic selector with variables

Tags: jquery, variables, dynamic

I am currently in the process of learning javascript (jquery). I am building a plugin that creates simple accordion menus but have run into a issue whilst creating a dynamic variable.

```
(function($){

    jQuery.accordify = function(settings){

        $defaults = {
            section : null,
            content : null,
            animation: 'slide',
            speed: 500
        }

        var defaults = $defaults;
        var settings = $.extend(defaults, settings);

        $animation = {
            slide : {in : 'slideDown('+settings.speed+')', out: 'slideUp('+settings.speed+')'},
            fade : {in: 'fadeIn('+settings.speed+')', out: 'fadeOut('+settings.speed+')'}
        }

        var animation = $animation.+settings.animation; // equvilent to 'animation.slide'

        alert(animation.in); // should return 'slideUp(500)'

    }

})(jQuery);
```

The variable **animation** is trying to reference the equvilent to **animation.slide** which is defined in the *settings/defaults* array, how would i get this working so that i will be able to call **animation.in** instead of **animation.slide.in**?.

Answer (score 0):

Syntaxt Error, notice the . and plus **.+**

```
  $animation.+settings
```

Also note: "in" is a reserved word, best to change it soon
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on that, i can easily change these but i am guessing the problem will still be there?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the problem i was facing, i changed the literal objects to variables and called the sub object like so... `animation[settings.animation]` which works.